# How can I make an unsupported inclined rail?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Normally, to place an inclined rail, you have to place it diagonally below another rail:

```
  _
_/█
```

Breaking the higher rail will leave the inclined one still inclined, like so:

```
_/█
```

… but breaking the "supporting" block beside the incline breaks both the block and the inclined rail. I once saw a video on YouTube that had an unsupported "jump" rail, so I know it's possible somehow, but the question is how?

How do I make an unsupported inclined rail that looks like this?

```
_/
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. The method you describe in the question creates a solitary inclined rail just fine. What is stopping you from doing it that way? What problem are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: I'm creating a minecart rail station or sorts, and one of the rail interchanges needs a jump that wouldn't have the extra block in hinder the minecart. I've encountered a few other times where aesthetics warranted such an incline. I once found a video on Youtube that had the rail as I described, but I've since lost the link.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It's not clear in the question you're talking about an unsupported rail. Here, let me edit it…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to create an incline like that by just placing rails and blocks, but you *can* use a sticky piston to "lift" the rails up. By pulling up one rail, the sticky piston makes the rail beside it inclined, and the rail it "lifted" breaks, leaving just the inclined rail with no block beside it. You can then remove the sticky piston. You can also use a normal piston to push a rail into the space where the unsupported incline will “aim”, which lifts the adjacent rail up into a slope and breaks the pushed piston, leaving just the unsupported inclined rail.

Either way is the same idea: get a rail into position with a piston so that it encourages the desired angled rail, without a block, so the rail breaks leaving its neighbour raised.

This video demonstrates how the second method works:

The thing to be careful of is that, once the piston has pulled up the rail and created the incline, any blocks that change adjacent to the incline will remind the game to check the rail to see if it's still a legal placement, and it will break. Essentially, anything that causes a [block update](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Block_update_detector) beside the incline will make it notice that it's not supposed to be inclined and will cause it to break. So if you need to power the "jump" rail, make sure to place your redstone power source before using the sticky piston.

Comment: Video in question is dead.

Comment: @pppery Thanks, I found another video doing the same trick in a slightly different way.